# How to make my Nvidia Graphic Card is the Default in PES 2015

Tags: graphics-card

I had PES 2015 game and it's always use Intel(R) HD Graphics as a default 
How to change that to Nvidia ?

Comment: The simplest way is to right click on the game's shortcut and select `Run with graphics processor -> High-performance NVIDIA processor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Vinayak's answer:
To default that choice you can follow Vinayak's instructions but then instead of clicking `High-performance NVIDIA processor` you click on the option to change the default GPU.
The NVIDIA-configuration panel pops open on `Manage 3D-settings` -> the 2nd tab `Program settings` where you can select for each seperate program which GPU should be used.
If your program/game doesn't show up in the dropdown list, click browse, locate your game-folder (PES 2015 in your case) and search and select the .exe (PES2015.exe I presume).
Select the preferred GPU, and don't forget to save/apply the settings.

Answer (score 0):

[Found this on a blog post](http://www.proevopatch.com/article/37/pes-2015-settings/) and it works for me:

> If your game detecs your integrated graphic card as primary and shows low power in requirements tab, try disabling this card in your system and switch to dedicated one. Control panel -> managing devices -> disable integrated card and restart device. If your screen got blanked, restart computer and enable it again or try finding option in BIOS.