# PES 2015 does not recognize my GeForce card

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

*Pro Evolution Soccer 2015* does not recognize my GeForce card. 
I set the settings on my Nvidia card to high performance, but it still uses the intel integrated graphics card.

> Nvidia driver version v344.15
>
> Laptop Asus n550jk
>
> GeForce 750m
>
> integrated Intel Graphics.

**How can I make PES use my Nvidia card instead?**

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.pesedit.com/forums/showthread.php?24934-Settings-exe-cannot-read-dedicated-GPU), [here](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/790141/nvidia-gtx-850m-not-recognized-by-pro-evolution-soccer-2015/) and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/287680/discussions/0/624075036519635079/).

EDIT: [Flagged as duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/841614/how-to-make-my-nvidia-graphic-card-is-the-default-in-pes-2015).

To make it **use** your Nvidia GPU:

The simplest way is to right click on the game's shortcut and select `Run with graphics processor>High-performance NVIDIA processor`.

To default to that action:

1. Open **Nvidia Control Panel**
2. Select **Manage 3D Settings**.
3. Select **Program settings** and click on **PES2015**
4. Under **Preferred Graphics Processor** change it to your Nvidia graphics card instead of the default Auto-select.

The game will be playable now but you still cannot change the resolution in-game.

To make it **recognize** your Nvidia GPU:

Unfortunately there is no current solution to make it recognize your dedicated GPU. This also happened in PES2014 until [Master Jenk*y released his great FileLoader](http://www.pesedit.com/forums/showthread.php?24934-Settings-exe-cannot-read-dedicated-GPU).

Comment: i try this before it didnt work however thank you

Comment: @Reza how did you know it didn't work? Did you compare the frame rates?

Comment: yes i compare now i saw a video on youtube and do some instructon's

Comment: and its work do it its on your link above thank's